# how to use Repeater for insert ,update, delete, select in table using sql sever

Tags: asp.net

```
private void BindRepeater()
    {
        //string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ADDArea",con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "select");
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
                        Repeater1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

protected void submit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string AreaName = Area_txt.Value;

        //string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ADDArea"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@action", "insert");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@areanama", AreaName);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        this.BindRepeater();
    }
```

Comment: You need to elaborate more detail about what you want to implement.

Comment: Explain what you want to achieve and what have you searched before posting the question. It seems basic CRUD operations are required and there are tons of articles on internet regarding this specific thing.